# Ist Praxist ein deutsches Wort?

Tags: vocabulary, neologism

Ich war vorgestern bei meiner Hausärztin. Sie hat jetzt neue Sprechstundenhilfen. Diese haben an der Wartezimmertür ein Schild angebracht:

> Bitte diese Tür schließen. Ihre **Praxisten**

Ich habe das Wort *Praxist* zu googeln versucht, wurde aber in deutschen Texten nicht fündig.
War ich nun nur zu faul beim Googeln oder ist das wirklich kein deutsches Wort?

Comment: Das Wort steht nicht im Duden

Comment: @JonasDralle... viele Wörter stehen nicht im Duden. Das sagt wenig.

Answer (score 11):

Letzten Endes hängt es davon ab, wie Du *deutsches Wort* und überhaupt *Wort* definierst. Zur Illustration des Problems bediene ich mich folgender Wörter:

- *Ball*
- *Korbball*
- *Stangenball*
- *Gefalt*
- *Düateßigän*

Die letzten drei Wörter habe ich mir selbst ausgedacht. Nimm für diese Antwort an, dass niemand anderes diese Wörter jemals verwendet hat.

***Ball*** und ***Düateßigän*** dürften in ihrer Klassifizierung unstrittig sein: Ersteres ist ein deutsches Wort, letzteres nicht. Jede Definition von *deutsches Wort,* die zu einem anderen Ergebnis kommt, wäre ziemlich unbrauchbar, da entweder nichts oder alles ein deutsches Wort wäre. ***Korbball*** unterscheidet sich von *Ball* nur dadurch, dass es zusammengesetzt ist. Es wird ebenfalls häufig verwendet, findet sich in Wörterbüchern und hat klare Bedeutungen. Es gibt viele deutsche Wörter, bei denen wir kaum noch wahrnehmen, dass sie zusammengesetzt sind, z. B. *vielleicht* oder *Drittel.*

***Stangenball*** ist schon im Graubereich. Wie *Korbball* folgt es hochproduktiven Bildungsregeln (mehr dazu gleich), aber man findet es nicht in Wörterbüchern. Wenn *Korbball* ohne Zusammenhang steht, kann angenommen werden, dass es sich auf eines der Folgenden bezieht:

- eine Sportart, bei der ein Ball auf Körbe gespielt wird
- das Sportgerät dieser Sportart

Das Wort *Stangenball* hingegen ist nicht etabliert, Bestandteil des Wortschatzes, oder in Wörterbüchern verzeichnet. Dies drückt sich insbesondere dadurch aus, dass im Gegensatz zu *Korbball* ohne Zusammenhang deutlich weniger klar ist, wofür es steht. Denkbar ist z. B. Folgendes:

- eine Sportart, bei der ein Ball auf Stangen gespielt wird (analog zu *Korbball)*
- eine Sportart, bei der die Spieler einen Ball mit Stangen spielen (analog zu *Fußball, Handball,* usw.)
- eine Sportart, bei der die Spieler auf Stangen balancierend einen Ball spielen (analog zu *Wasserball)*
- Sportgeräte dieser Sportarten
- eine Kugel, die mit Stangen versehen ist
- eine Tanzveranstaltung, die irgendwie Stangen involviert

Aber nur weil es nicht gebraucht wird, ist das Wort *Stangenball* nicht falsch in dem Sinne, dass es in einem Text korrigiert werden müsste. Es ist eine korrekt gebildete Zusammensetzung. Dass diese als eigenes Wort behandelt wird, ist letzten Endes ein Aspekt der deutschen Rechtschreibung. Zum Beispiel im Englischen werden derartige Zusammensetzungen auf dieselbe Weise gebildet, aber vorwiegend getrennt geschrieben. Ich würde *Stangenball* deshalb nicht als Neologismus auffassen, sondern schlicht als Anwendung der deutschen Grammatik. Ob es sich bei *Stangenball* um ein deutsches Wort handelt, hängt also davon ab, ob man Verwendung als Kriterium auffasst oder nicht.

***Gefalt*** ist aus *falten* in Analogie zu *sehen → Gesicht, beten → Gebet* usw. gebildet. Es geht noch einen Schritt weiter als *Stangenball,* da das Prinzip, gemäß dessen es gebildet wurde, nicht mehr [produktiv (im linguistischen Sinne ist)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wortbildung), d. h., wir nutzen dieses Prinzip nicht mehr regelmäßig und ohne groß darüber nachzudenken, um Wörter zu bilden. Stattdessen greifen wir höchstens in Ausnahmefällen und bewusst darauf zurück, wenn konventionelle Wortbildungsmechanismen und existente Wörter (z. B. *Faltung* oder *Falte)* unsere Wortschatzlücke nicht adäquat schließen. Beachte, dass *Gefalt* ähnliche »Probleme« hat wie *Stangenball:* Ohne Zusammenhang ist deutlich weniger klar als bei *Gesicht,* was damit gemeint ist. Im Gegensatz zu *Stangenball* würde ich *Gefalt* als Neologismus ansehen. Dieses Wort als deutsches Wort aufzufassen, bedarf sehr lockerer Kriterien.

***Praxist*** schließlich verhält sich ähnlich wie *Gefalt.* Den Bildungsmechanismus (siehe auch [Crissovs Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/24271/2594)) mag man als etwas produktiver ansehen, aber er ist nicht so produktiv, dass wir ihn unbewusst verwenden. Wie schon *Stangenball* und *Gefalt* wird es nicht weitläufig verwendet (ich konnte zumindest nichts diesbezüglich finden) und ohne Zusammenhang ist nicht klar, wovon die Rede ist:

- jemand, der eine Praxis betreibt (analog zu *Maschinist* oder *Flötist)*
- jemand, der sich für Praxis (als Konzept) einsetzt oder es vertritt (analog zu *Utopist, Perfektionist*), z. B. die Anhänger der [Praxisphilosophie](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Praxisphilosophie) (siehe [diesen Kommentar](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/24242/ist-praxist-ein-deutsches-wort/24271#comment55545_24271))
- jemand, der praktisch denkt oder handelt (analog zu *Spezialist, Solist, Realist)*
- jemand, der Praxen aufbaut, ausstattet, o. Ä. (analog zu *Novellist, Porträtist)*
- jemand, der Praxen oder Praxis studiert oder untersucht (analog zu *Linguist)*

Ich denke, dass es schon einer sehr weiten Definition von *deutsches Wort* bedarf, damit *Praxist* sie erfüllt. Aber letztlich sind Definitionen ja kein reiner Selbstzweck, und Du musst für Dich selbst entscheiden, wieso Dich eigentlich interessiert, ob *Praxist* ein deutsches Wort ist. Es ist kein etablierter Begriff, bei dem Du erwarten kannst, dass er ohne Probleme verstanden wird, aber es steht Teilhabern einer Sprache frei, Wortschatzlücken zu füllen und diesbezüglich gibt es nichts an *Praxist* auszusetzen.

Comment: Äh, ja, schön, damit wären wir im Grundlegenden. Für die einen ist alles, was nicht im Duden steht, nicht ok und für die anderen ist alles, was eventuell mal im Duden stehen könnte, auch ok. Ich verstehe den ausufernden Text über wie eventuell irgendwelche Worte mal zustandekommen könnten, nicht.

Comment: @Karl: Kannst Du Dein Unverständnis irgendwie spezifizieren?

Answer (score 10):

Ich halte das eher für eine Scherzbezeichnung des Praxisteams. Mir kam das Wort als Muttersprachler bisher nicht unter.

Eine praktisch arbeitende Person bezeichnet man üblich als Praktiker.

Die Bezeichnung liest sich für mich, wie Schilder in Gemeinschaftsküchen, auf denen eine "Küchenfee" darum bittet, die Tassen in die Spüle zu stellen.

Comment: das ist keine schlechte Erklärung, andererseits hatte ich nicht den Eindruck, daß diese neuen Damen sehr humorvoll sind.

Comment: Das Problem ist, daß es alles Damen sind in der Praxis. Die Bezeichnung *Praxisten* ist daher sexistisch und nicht pc, müßte *Praxistinnen* sein. Wenn die städtische Genderbeauftragte da vorbeikommt, kriegen die ein Riesenproblem!

Comment: Küchenfee wäre demnach ebenso sexistisch Männern gegenüber, da sie quasi aus einem Fantasy/Mythologie-Kontext wie ein generisches Femininum angesehen werden können.

Comment: @AndréKleinschmidt: Typischerweise ist die Idee vom "generischen Femininum/Maskulinum" ein Argument warum ein Begriff *gerade nicht* sexistisch ist. Du mischt da also zwei Seiten einer Diskussion, vielleicht hab ich hier einfach auch nur einen Witz nicht verstanden.

Comment: ja, ich hab wohl aus Gewohnheit "generisch" geschrieben, hatte aber das Wort stereotyp im Kopf. O_o.. ich kann den Kommentar nicht mehr ändern... seltsam.

Answer (score 5):

Natürlich ist *Praxist, -en* ein deutsches Wort. Muttersprachler verstehen mindestens im Kontext, wer damit gemeint ist, und auch fortgeschrittene Zweitsprachler. Es ist allerdings kein besonders häufiges und damit konventionelles Wort.

Sprache entwickelt sich ständig weiter und solche Neuschöpfungen leisten dazu einen essentiellen Beitrag. Allerdings folgt das Wort nur scheinbar einem gebräuchlichem morphologischen Schema.

Substantive auf *-ist* (Fem. *+in*, Pl. *+en*) stammen in der Regel aus einer romanischen Sprache und ihr Stamm wird mit anderen charakteristischen Endungen (inkl. der leeren) verwendet:

1. *femin+in,  Femin+ist,  Femin+ismus,  femin+istisch; Femin+inum*
2. *extrem,   Extrem+ist, Extrem+ismus, extrem+istisch*
3. *Tour,       Tour+ist,   Tour+ismus,   tour+istisch; tour+en* (französische Wurzel)
4. *Marx,       Marx+ist,   Marx+ismus,   marx+istisch* (Eigennamenwurzel)
5. *Sex,         Sex+ist,    Sex+ismus,    sex+istisch*
6. *Rass+e,     Rass+ist,   Rass+ismus,   rass+istisch; rass+isch* (deutsche Wurzel)
7. *Organ,    *Organ+ist,  Organ+ismus,  organ+isch*
8. *Mechan+ik, Mechan+iker, Mechan+ismus, mechan+isch* (griechische Wurzel)

Dem Muster aus (2–5) folgt *Prax+is/Praxis+, Prax+ist/Praxis+t* offenbar nicht und auch nicht (7–8); ebensowenig den weiteren ähnlichen, leicht abweichenden Mustern, die man so findet (*Realist, Nationalist, Egoist, Populist, Patriot, Zyniker, Katholik* …). Wie in (1) und (6) entfällt die Endung des Grundwortes und wird durch *+ist* ersetzt, nur dass die vorhandene Endung *-is* schon dem Anfang der neuen entspricht.

*Praxis* ist aber auch ein eher ungewöhnliches Wort. Auf *-xis* enden von im deutschen Sprachgebrauch halbwegs frequenten Wörtern sonst nur noch *Taxi+s* (Plural), *Galaxis* (gebräuchlicher: *Galaxie*) und *Axis* (gebräuchlicher: *Achse*). Es ist natürlich etymologisch verwandt mit *prakt+izieren, Prakt+ik, Prakt+ikum, Prakt+iker, prakt+isch*, aber für deutsche morphologische Verhältnisse ist eine Änderung von *kt* zu *x*/*ks* im Stamm schon recht intransparent und geht hier auch mit semantischer Differenzierung einher. **Prakt+ist+en* wäre daher keine konsequente Bildung für ‚Praxispersonal‘ gewesen und genausowenig wäre *Prakt+iker* angemessen gewesen – eher noch **Prax+iker*.

Comment: In anderem Kontext kann man gelegentlich die Bezeichnung **Praxist** für einen Anhänger der [Praxisphilosophie](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Praxisphilosophie) finden. So ganz verkehrt ist deine Antwort also nicht.

Comment: Das ist doch Käse. Nach Deiner Logik kann ich "-ist" an alle Wörter anhängen und das neue Wort ist automatisch ein deutsches Wort? Bananist? Tigerist? Schnapsist? Hemdist?

Comment: @Robert, bist Du evuentell kein Crissovist?

Comment: @Robert An viele auf jeden Fall. Ein Sprachspiel und vielleicht setzt es sich durch, in den allermeisten Fällen aber nicht.c

Comment: Crissov, ich habe das Gefühl, dass die inzwischen 5 Downvotes auf Deiner weder schlampigen, noch falschen, noch irreführenden, noch am Thema vorbei gehenden Antwort eine [Meta]-Diskussion wert ist. Ich habe keine Ahnung, was die Leute mit diesen extrem vielen Downvotes bezwecken wollen. So ist das Voting-System auf SE jedenfalls nicht gedacht.

Comment: Nette morphologische Analyse. Allerdings werden die populärsten Neologismen nicht von Sprachwissenschaftlern ersonnen oder konstruiert und folgen eher selten den üblichen Grammatikregeln der Zielsprache. Die Antwort ist sprachwissenschaftlich interessant, hilft aber beim Abwägen darüber, ob das Wort alltagstauglich ist nicht wirklich weiter. Andere Worte, wie googeln (statt googlen) oder simsen (statt SMSen) haben ihrerseits auch keine sprachwissenschaftliche Konstruktion benötigt um sich im Allgemeingebrauch durchzusetzen.

Comment: "Es ist allerdings kein besonders häufiges" Leichte Untertreibung, oder? Bisher haben wir genau eine Verwendung in der Bedeutung von "Mitarbeiter einer Praxis" die mal jemand in freier Wildbahn gesehen hat. Und für das Kriterium "ist ein deutsches Wort" gibt es strengere Kriterien als "ein Muttersprachler kann sich den Sinn im Kontext erschliessen", meiner Meinung nach. Trotzdem für mich eine interessante Anwort wegen der Erklärung zur Wortbildung.

Comment: @Takkat Ich habe mich bereits bei vorherigen Antworten damit abgefunden, dass es hier viele (aber nicht nur) konservativ-präskriptive Laien, die bewerten, gibt.

Comment: @AndréKleinschmidt Die Linguistik erfindet Wörter nicht, sie beschreibt aber Gesetzmäßigkeiten für ihre Entstehung. Sicher gibt es auch für _+ist_ diverse relevante Veröffentlichungen, die ich aber für meine Antwort nicht recherchiert habe.

Comment: @0x6d64 Allein für „Wort“ gibt es zig Definitionen, in denen Häufigkeit selten bis nie das wichtigste Kriterium ist – Konventionalität schon eher. Davon abgesehen: ja, das war etwas euphemistisch.

Comment: @Takkat, tja wie ist das System denn dann gedacht? Ist es demokratisch, dann muß man das akzeptieren. Oder soll es nicht-demokratisch entwickelt werden zu einen autoritären?

Comment: @Karl: http://german.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote & http://german.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up & http://german.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down. Für Downvotes steht da "Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an **egregiously sloppy** (schludrig), **no-effort-expended** post (ohne Ausarbeitung), or an answer that is **clearly** and perhaps dangerously **incorrect** (eindeutig oder gefährlich falsch)", das trifft hier alles nicht zu.

Comment: @Takkat, Oh ja, die Vorschriften, wenn man die nicht einhält, hier ist ja die Gruppe für deutsche Sprache. ich finde nur leider im obigen Text nichts, das mir verbietet, eine Antwort runterzustimmen, wenn ich denke, daß hier "Thema verfehlt" zutrifft. Der Text, den Du zitiert, ist eine Empfehlung, keine Vorschrift, da hast Du wohl als Deutscher was mißverstanden.

Comment: **All discussion on this should go there: http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/951/how-should-i-use-my-votes**

Comment: Warm folgt das Wort nicht dem Muster der ersten Beispiele? Ist Praxismus etwa kein deutsches Wort?

Comment: Danke, @CarstenSchultz! Da war noch eine falsche Referenz drin, (1–5|6) statt (2–5). In der hier vorgestellten Verwendung gehört _Praxist_ vermutlich nicht in ein Wortfeld mit _Praxismus_, in der von Takkat im ersten Kommentar erwähnten hingegen schon eher. Soll heißen, hier ist ein Praxist nicht jemand, der Praxismus ausübt. Es ging mir aber tatsächlich eher um die Ähnlichkeit von _-is_ und _-ist_, was mir aber auch erst im Laufe des Antwortens klar geworden ist.

Answer (score 0):

**Praxist** ist kein deutsches Wort. Ich bin mir sicher, es handelt sich hier um einen Rechtschreibfehler - es sollte wohl **Praxisteam** heißen.

Comment: kann wohl sein, aber irgendjemand, zumindestens die Ärztin, müßte das dann doch bemerken und korrigieren. So macht es einen schlechten Eindruck.

Comment: Auf den zweiten Gedanken, doch eher nein, denn dann müßte es *Ihr Praxisteam* heißen. Das wären dann drei Schreibfehler in zwei Worten, wenn das gemeint ist.

Comment: Da hast du allerdings recht.

Comment: Deutsch kann Glücksache sein. Sprechstundenhilfen sind oft sehr junge Mädchen/Damen. Da kann schom mal sprachlich ein Mißgeschick passieren. Oder das hat sich bei dieser "Praxisclique" so eingebürgert, bis mal jemand auf diesen Fehler aufmerksam macht.

Comment: Aber die promovierte Chefin sollte Deutsch doch beherrschen IMHO.

Comment: Hat sie denn genug Zeit um auf das Schild zu achten? Manche Ärzte sind schon verdammt überarbeitet.

Comment: Es ist kaum ein übersehener Rechtschreibfehler, sondern eine klar als solche erkennbare Wortschöpfung, die als (augenzwinkernde) Alternative zum Wort 'Praxisteam' interpretiert werden könnte. Der  Begriff 'Team' – so verbreitet er auch sein mag – ist im Bereich der Berufstätigkeit durchaus nicht ohne Kritik. Siehe z.B. http://www.brandeins.de/archiv/2002/zusammenarbeit/du-und-das-team/ oder Suchworte: Mythos Team

Comment: Ich bezweifle, das die Verfasser sich so viele Gedanken zum Wort 'Team' gemacht haben.

Answer (score 0):

Ich habe das Wort noch nie gehört. Entweder war das bewusst kein völlig korrektes deutsches Wort oder das Praxisteam hat's nicht so mit dem Deutschen.

Auf jeden Fall sind -ist Endungen populär im Englischen, und da heutzutage das Englisch immer dominanter wird (u.a. durch Digitalisierung und Computer) werden wir solche Konstrukte wahrscheinlich auch in Zukunft öfter sehen.