# Ist das Wort "Ungleichnis" zulässig?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Das Wort *Gleichnis* lässt sich im Duden zwar nachschlagen, *Ungleichnis* jedoch nicht. Meinem Gefühl nach würde ich sagen, dass Ungleichnis ein valides deutsches Wort ist. Meine Frage lautet also, ob dem so ist.

Comment: Related: [Ist Praxist ein deutsches Wort?](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/24242/2594)

Comment: Wurde die Zulassung rechtzeitig auf amtlichem Vordruck unter Angabe einer exakten Definition der Bedeutung bei der Zwischenstaatlichen Wortzulassungskommission beantragt?  Ansonsten ist die Verwendung natürlich unzulässig.

Comment: Zulässig in welchem Kontext? Scrabble? Umgangssprache? Dudenredaktion? Ansonsten siehe eine gleichartige Frage im Kommentar oben. Unabhängig davon: Willkommen!

Comment: Aber obwohl die zwei verwandt sind, ist es kein echtes Duplikat … höchstens die Antworten sind Duplikate … hach, wir sollten daraus eine kanonische Frage machen.

Comment: @Jan gute Idee. (Und deshalb kein vtc von mir.)

Comment: Die Frage ist doch, ob es von einer breiten Mehrheit verstanden werden würde. Vermutlich wäre das ohne genauere Definition nicht so. Interessant wäre die Definition aber. Wenn ein Gleichnis eine bildhafte, vergleichende Geschichte ist, die den Hörer zu einer Erkenntnis bringen will und die Vorsilbe "Un-" etwas ins Gegenteil kehrt, was soll dann ein Ungleichnis sein? Eine Geschichte, die nicht bildhaft/vergleichend ist, aber eine Erkenntnis auslöst? Oder eine, die überhaupt keine Erkenntnis auslöst?